# Play any video format

Tags: macos, cocoa, video, avplayer, playback

I need to play any kind of video in my desktop application in MAC.

I could play .mp4 videos, but I can't play .avi videos using AVPlayer.

How can I do this? Should I use AVPlayer and configure this in a different way or should I use another framework.

Answer (score 2):

AVPlayer can only play a select few formats: MPEG-4 or QuickTime containers containing H.264 video and AAC or AC-3 audio, MP3 files, and very little else.

QTKit, although deprecated and much more limited in functionality, can play a much broader range of formats—whatever QuickTime can play. This includes AVI containers and most video and audio codecs.

If you want to play anything else, you will have to either use QTKit (despite its deprecation) and bundle any custom codecs you need; or find, license (if needed), and bundle a complete third-party solution.